# Categorize default rivers data in R

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart, frequency

I want to categorize default `rivers` data in R into:

- “tiny” (<500)
- “short” (<1500)
- “medium” (<3000)
- “long” (>=3000)

And then plot a pie chart that visualizes frequency of these four categories.

How do I do it in R in quickest way?

Comment: Please, can you add your tries?

Comment: Have you tried `cut`?

Answer (score 2):

```
breaks <- c(0,500,1500,3000,Inf)
labels <- c("tiny", "short", "medium", "long")
groups <- cut(rivers, breaks=breaks, labels=labels)

pie(table(groups))
```

The result:

[image: rivers]